# Ionide Intellisense quick fixes doesn't add code to file - F# Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, intellisense, ionide

When I press `CTRL+.` for quick fixes or the click the light bulb (show fixes) I get the dialog in the below image. However, when I press enter or click an item in the quick fixes dialog no code is added to my document i.e. nothing happens.

[image: Show fixes]

Does anyone know how to fix this? In the given example, I'd expect selecting "Open System" to add the line "open System" at the top of the document.

Environment:

Windows 10

Visual Studio Code 1.46.1

Ionide-fsharp 4.14.0

Comment: This works well for me.  Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension?  uninstalling VSCode?

Comment: Thanks for confirming this works. I tried uninstalling the extension and VSCode, but I still get the same behaviour.

Comment: Seems like a bug in the extension. Adding link to your issue on GitHub: (https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/issues/1396)